# Counting figures, tables and citations in a document

Tags: counters, word-count, texcount

My idea is to use [TeXcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texcount)  to scan my document and output the number of words, figures, tables, equations and citations.

I've been looking at the documentation for TeXcount and it seems that words and equations are handled by default, but I don't see how to give different environments their own counters (and citations are a different matter). Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you have any other object you want to count, but for those that you mentioned, here's how I worked it out:

- **words:** use [texcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texcount) (see example below)
- **figures:** use the default LaTeX counter `figure`
- **tables:** use the default LaTeX counter `table`
- **equations:** use the default LaTeX counter `equation`
- **citations:** use the [lastbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lastbib) package

You can display the current value of any counter using `\arabic{NameOfTheCounter}`. To display the maximum value assigned to a counter anywhere in the document, the [totcount](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/totcount/totcount.pdf) package should be helpful.

The following is the colophon I recently started to use. Comments provided for your convenience

```
% characters count: the value is printed in the ancillary file char-count.tex
\bash[ignoreStderr=true,stdoutFile=char-count.tex]
echo `texcount -quiet -merge -1 -char cub-ant-sys-lit-sur.tex`|sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
\END
% word count: the value is printed in the ancillary file word-count.tex
\bash[ignoreStderr=true,stdoutFile=word-count.tex]
echo `texcount -quiet -merge -1 insert-name-of-file-here.tex`|sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
\END
\section{Colophon}
Document data: \thepage{} pages; % display number of pages
\input{word-count} words; % display number of words
\input{char-count}characters; % display number of characters
\arabic{figure} figures; % display number of figures
\LastBib{} references; % display number of references in the bibliography (not the number of citations)
\arabic{footnote} numbered notes; % display number of footnotes
\arabic{glossaryentry} glossary entries. % display number of glossary entries (using package glossaries)
```

In the example I didn't need the package `totcount`, because the colophon is the last text appearing in the document.

Comment: I'd prefer to have these statistics in a separate text file instead of my LaTeX document. Is there a way to output these counters to a text file, perhaps using your `\bash` command?

Comment: Of course! Here's an example:

\bash[ignoreStderr=true,stdoutFile=word-count.tex]
echo `texcount -quiet -merge -1 cub-ant-sys-the-pro.tex`|sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
\END`

this editor does not escape very well the reverse `'`

Comment: Right, this is like in your initial example. But how do I output counters like the figure counter (LaTeX counters rather than TeXcount counters)?